# Added Extra White Space in Products Image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, products, dimensions

My Products Image is,

[image]

**Note : View image as new tab in chrome**

[image]

**Note : View image as new tab in chrome**

By default magento added white space.

Website View:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default magento adds white frame around the image, so to remove it you should use **keepFrame(false)** to remove white spaces around it.

`resize(1200)` is used to resize with proportion. you can change it as you need.

Your image code will be like :

```
$_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                ->keepFrame(false)
                ->resize(1200);
```

Comment: where is the file located?

Comment: you need to add where ever is image is called like, media.phtml file, listing.phtml file etc... just you need to replace the piece of code where image is being called.